# Grep a block of text using pattern

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed, bash-scripting

I have short text file, where i should make output of data using special pattern. My file:

```
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
11 test1
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3
17 test1
18 test4
```

One by one, from test1 to test2 and to test3.
So... I have written the comand:

```
sed '/test1.*\|test2.*\|test3/!d' filename
```

And in output i have result:

```
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
11 test1
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3
17 test1
```

In this case, i have lines, that i not need:

```
11 test1

17 test1
```

This lines don't go one after one. How i can do result, that i need ? Please help me. Thanks for your attention. i Should get this result:

```
99 test1
88 test2
10 test3
12 test1
13 test2
14 test3
```

Comment: Do you need a one-liner or could this also be a small script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you data is in a file called `test`, here a one-liner, but without `sed`:

```
cat test | tr '\n' '_' | grep -o '[0-9]*\stest1_[0-9]*\stest2_[0-9]*\stest3' | tr '_' '\n'
```

What this line is doing

1. Changing the content of `test` from multiple lines to one line with `tr '\n' '_'`
2. Get only the part, where `test1`, `test2` and `test3` are behind the other with `grep -o '[0-9]*\stest1_[0-9]*\stest2_[0-9]*\stest3'`
3. Returning from one line to multiple lines with `tr '_' '\n'`